# Is there an onscreen way I can tell gruesome feast is working?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I recently unlocked the passive ability [gruesome feast](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/passive/gruesome-feast).  It states:

> Whenever you are healed by a health globe, you gain 10% of your maximum Mana and 10% Intelligence for 10 seconds. The Intelligence bonus can stack up to 5 times.

However, whenever I get a health globe, nothing seems to happen.  I'm used to other similar abilities showing stacks where "buffs" are normally displayed.  Is this not the case with gruesome feast?  Is there an onscreen way to see that I'm getting the buff, or do I have to take it on faith?  (or am I just ***doing it wrong*** ?)

Comment: try to keep your character menu open, if you are getting an int boost you should be able to see a DPS increase

Comment: Blizzard have stated they didn't want to expose all buffs/debuffs a while back when discussing things like Force Weapon, it may well be that this information isn't clearly exposed within the interface, in which case you will want to go down the route of monitoring your character sheet for the intelligence increase in order to confirm it is working.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I see that via the character sheet my int does increase.  If it is the case as @pixel points out that Blizzard intends to not expose all buffs/debuffs that's unfortunate.  It's hard as it is to tell what's going on half the time - requiring my char sheet to be open to tell just makes it that much worse....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no visible buff, the only way to see that it is working is to look at your character sheet.  You will be able to see your intelligence and DPS at the buffed level, and then see it drop again when the effect wears off.